# How much you should earn when you start coding in new programming language?

Tags: software-industry, salary

I think about change my job - I'm mobile developer with around two and a half years professional experience now (Android mainly, but iOS too), but I would like to try Scala programming now.

I wonder how much can I suggest I want to earn during interview? I guess it won't be an amount I could get as an mobile developer (and I accept it), but I believe it shouldn't be also an amount someone completely new to programming would earn.

Comment: How much do you know about the language? What does 2,5 mean?

Comment: The comma is the decimal point in some places so that could be 2.5

Comment: I'm working for 2.5 years and I think I'm good worker and know Java/Objective-C quite well. Also I'm quick learner.

I don't know too much about Scala - I have finished Coursera course about Scala and now I'm taking Reactive programming course, but I don't have any professional experience.

Comment: Pure Scala jobs are very difficult to find, even if you have some Scala experience.  Same goes for any other FP language.

Comment: When considering the salary I would consider the position at forefront. E.g. an accountant that uses an uncommon piece of software to perform her job is still an accountant. OTOH, a programmer which is skilled at an uncommon language can be a selling point that adds value. I've heard that experienced COBOL programmers can demand higher salaries, for example. But your comment suggests you're still  unsure of your skill in Scala. As an analogy, would you pay extra for a car with an experimental new feauture?